# If-condition cannot be used in multline environment?

Tags: conditionals, multline

`Incomplete \ifx` error raises when compiling the following tex code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline} % <- Replacing `multline` with `equation` can fix the problem.
  \iftrue
    \begin{aligned} h \end{aligned} % <- Removing `aligned` can fix the problem.
  \fi
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is presumably an issue with grouping. If you enclose the `aligned` environment in braces the code compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline} % <- Replacing `multline` with `equation` can fix the problem.
  \iftrue {
    \begin{aligned} h \end{aligned} % <- Removing `aligned` can fix the problem.
      }
  \fi
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I found enclosing the if-conditioning in braces will also solve the problem.